# How to create a new file in dbt Cloud

Tags: dbt

I wanted to create a file on DBT cloud, but i do not have a button like on a video that suppose to be right when you hover over a folder to create a new file. Could someone please explain how to do it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DjcQ.png)

Answer (score 3):

I guess this happens because you are in the main branch (read only), if that's the case then you need to create a new branch first.